# How to format Ansible result from list to strings?

Tags: ansible

I have this result from a Ansible playbook

```
['infra', 'mgmt', 'common', 'Heroes', 'oneaciapp']
```

and I want to send the result to a teams room.

How can I format it, so I get this result:

```
infra
mgmt
common
Heroes
oneaciapp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join('\n')` to join the elements of the list into desired string. Check out the output of 2nd `debug`.

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    myvar: "myhost"
    mylist:
      - infra
      - mgmt
      - common
      - Heros
      - oneaiapp

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ mylist }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ mylist |join('\n')}}"
```

Here is the output:

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

['infra', 'mgmt', 'common', 'Heros', 'oneaiapp']


TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

infra
mgmt
common
Heros
oneaiapp


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```